# VSCode extension - access timeline tab

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way for a VSCode extension to access the timeline tab? I searched the docs but I couldn't find anything?

To be more specific, I'd like to watch for changes in certain files and get the diff of that change. I managed to register a listener on file changes, but I also want the actual change. This is what I have so far:

```
const vscode = require("vscode");

function activate(context) {
  const workspacePath = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders[0];
  const watcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher(
    new vscode.RelativePattern(workspacePath, "**/package.json")
  );
  
  watcher.onDidChange((e) => {
    console.log(e); # this only prints the file path, not the content.
  }
}

module.exports = {activate};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Timeline API available yet. There is however, a *proposed API* being discussed for a while (https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84297), but the last comment is one year old.

But, if you need to detect file changes (not necessarily the file being edited by the user, but any file in the workspace) and compare its content, you need not only the `FileSystemWatcher` but also some lib that provides you text differencing algorithm, like [jsdiff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff).

Hope this helps